# Each Selection in D3 Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js, pie-chart

currently I am trying to design dynamic pie chart whereby the pie chart's slices will change according to the random generated data. Below is the code.

```js
var dataset = [
    { name: 'Smooth', percent: 40.00, class: 'custom-normal' },
    { name: 'Moderate', percent: 10.00, class: 'custom-warning' },
    { name: 'Heavy', percent: 50.00, class: 'custom-danger' }
];
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2; //Math.min return the smallest value between width and height (for optimization purposes)

var colorValues = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["Smooth", "Moderate", "Heavy"]).range(["#605A4C", "#ff9900", "#ff1a1a"]);
var percent = "percent"; //predefine the legend of dataset (the string index)
var category = "class";
var name = "name";

var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d[percent]; })
    .sort(null)
    .padAngle(.02); //the gap

var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100) //optimization
    .outerRadius(radius - 20); //optimization

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attrs({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        class: "shadow"
    }).append("g")
    .attrs({
        transform: 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
    });
svg.append('g')
    .attrs({
        class: 'slices'
    });

var path = svg.select('.slices')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter().append('path')
    .attrs({
        d: arc
    }).each(function(d, i) {
        this._current = d;
        console.log(this._current);
        console.log('okay!');
    }).attrs({
        class: function(d, i){
        return d[category];
        },
        fill: function(d, i) {
            console.log("this is color value" + colorValues());
            return colorValues(d[i]);
        }
    }); //initial details (this._current)


var randomGenerator = setInterval(function() {
    var data = dataset.map(function(d, i) {
        for (var key in d) {
            if (d[key] === "Smooth") {
                //console.log("smooth");
                dataset[0].percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                //console.log(dataset[0].percent);
            } else if (d[key] === "Moderate") {
                dataset[1].percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                //console.log(dataset[1].percent);
                //console.log("moderate");
            } else if (d[key] === "Heavy") {
                dataset[2].percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                //console.log(dataset[2].percent);
                //console.log("heavy");
            }
        }

    });

}, 3000);


var timer = setInterval(function() {
    pie.value(function(d) {
        return d[percent];
    }); // change the value function
    path = path.data(pie(dataset)); // compute the new angles
    path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
}, 3000);


// Store the displayed angles in _current.
// Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
// During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    console.log(this._current);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
    };
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div id="mydiv" class="widget">
    <div id="chart" class="Chart chart-container"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that the color of each slices is not scaled according to what I have defined earlier. i.e. :`var colorValues = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["Smooth", "Moderate", "Heavy"]).range(["#605A4C", "#ff9900", "#ff1a1a"]);`. I believe it should be the selection problem, however I found no clue on that. And yet, the class as well, it only get the first row of data in `var dataset` and apply to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

By pushing your data through the pie function, you are altering your data. While your initial structure is:

```
{ name: 'Smooth', percent: 40.00, class: 'custom-normal' }
```

After running this data through the pie function, the datum bound to each arc has the following structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Heavy",
    "percent": 48,
    "class": "custom-danger"
  },
  "index": 2,
  "value": 50,
  "startAngle": 3.1515926535897933,
  "endAngle": 6.283185307179586,
  "padAngle": 0.02
}
```

In your code you are coloring the wedges based on this:

```
fill: function(d, i) {
    console.log("this is color value" + colorValues());
    return colorValues(d[i]);
}
```

The `d` in `function(d) {}` refers to the datum, so it is just a single item in the input data (the datum bound to a particular arc), which is an object - the use of d[number] suggests that you anticipate an array. In any event, each time you run this function you will get `undefined`.

Instead access the property of the datum you want: `name` (I assume) and use:

```
fill: function(d, i) {
    console.log("this is color value" + colorValues());
    return colorValues(d.data.name);
}
```

```js
var dataset = [
    { name: 'Smooth', percent: 40.00, class: 'custom-normal' },
    { name: 'Moderate', percent: 10.00, class: 'custom-warning' },
    { name: 'Heavy', percent: 50.00, class: 'custom-danger' }
];
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2; //Math.min return the smallest value between width and height (for optimization purposes)

var colorValues = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["Smooth", "Moderate", "Heavy"]).range(["#605A4C", "#ff9900", "#ff1a1a"]);
var percent = "percent"; //predefine the legend of dataset (the string index)
var category = "class";
var name = "name";

var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d[percent]; })
    .sort(null)
    .padAngle(.02); //the gap

var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100) //optimization
    .outerRadius(radius - 20); //optimization

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attrs({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        class: "shadow"
    }).append("g")
    .attrs({
        transform: 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
    });
svg.append('g')
    .attrs({
        class: 'slices'
    });

var path = svg.select('.slices')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter().append('path')
    .attrs({
        d: arc
    }).each(function(d, i) {
        this._current = d;
        console.log(this._current);
        console.log('okay!');
    }).attrs({
        class: function(d, i){
        return d.data.class;
        },
        fill: function(d, i) {
            console.log("this is color value" + colorValues());
            return colorValues(d.data.name);
        }
    }); //initial details (this._current)


var randomGenerator = setInterval(function() {
    var data = dataset.map(function(d, i) {
        for (var key in d) {
            if (d[key] === "Smooth") {
                //console.log("smooth");
                dataset[0].percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                //console.log(dataset[0].percent);
            } else if (d[key] === "Moderate") {
                dataset[1].percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                //console.log(dataset[1].percent);
                //console.log("moderate");
            } else if (d[key] === "Heavy") {
                dataset[2].percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                //console.log(dataset[2].percent);
                //console.log("heavy");
            }
        }

    });

}, 3000);


var timer = setInterval(function() {
    pie.value(function(d) {
        return d[percent];
    }); // change the value function
    path = path.data(pie(dataset)); // compute the new angles
    path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
}, 3000);


// Store the displayed angles in _current.
// Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
// During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    console.log(this._current);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
    };
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div id="mydiv" class="widget">
    <div id="chart" class="Chart chart-container"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew. Yes this is exactly what i meant. However, may I know how can I solve the class problem? I wish to attach the class to each individual slice as well.

Comment: Sorry, updated the snippet, to access the class property you would use `d.data.class`, as the class was originally located at d.class, but after running it through pie() you have d.data.class

Comment: @cypatrick If this answer did solve your problem, you should consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. This will help future readers, who are facing the same problem, identifying the correct solution. See also [*"What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [*"What should I do when someone answers my question?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).